# Rgbdslam : svn co ... link not responding

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set up the workspace perfectly well.
But, after that , whenever i try to run the link svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg, the error keeps coming :
"svn: OPTIONS of 'http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com)"
Please help anyone as soon as possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195195/rgbdslam-:-svn-co-...-link-not-responding/) by [Mosam Dabhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19750/mosam-dabhi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Works for me. It's possible that this is just a temporary server glitch.

It's also possible that your version of SVN is too old, or your firewall or proxy is blocking access to google code for some reason.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mosam Dabhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19750/mosam-dabhi/) on 2014-10-17**:
Well, i don't think that it would be temporary server glitch as I have been trying to access this from last 2 days. All the sites and links are accessed by me except this.
Sir, other than that, if you are suggesting that there might be the reason of SVN version old, or firewall or proxy blocking,pl

**Comment by [Mosam Dabhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19750/mosam-dabhi/) on 2014-10-17**:
*Please suggest or give me a way out of it to resolve it. Other than that, if there is a possible way to directly download the file externally and unzip it in terminal, then also, please suggest me a way of how to do it.
Thank you

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-17**:
A quick google search suggests that this is a problem with a firewall or proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613149/svn-could-not-read-status-line-connection-was-closed-by-server

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-17**:
I don't know what version of SVN you have or what sort of firewall or proxy you're behind, so I can't give any more specific advice.